# IIS Security: Why is it dangerous to make locally hosted xml files writable by the application pool account?

Tags: asp.net, security, iis

I have a website that reads an xml file, caches the file's object model, and i have web pages that read from the cache. I now want to make that xml file writable by the application pool account that runs the website so it can be managed by the website.

I've heard from peers that making that file writable is a security risk because if a hacker were to hack the website, he could potentially use the app pool account to overwrite that xml file and put whatever he/she wants into that file. However, since that file is read by directly hitting the web cache (and not the xml file) and the application pool account has write access to it, doesn't that mean a hacker can modify the object model that represent the xml file, regardless if the xml file is writable? By modifying the web cache, the hacker could inflict the same damage as if he had access to the web cache. I don't see how making the xml file read-only makes the website safer from hackers.

Comment: What account reads the web cache? Is this web cache the Cache, i.e. the intrinsic Cache object that is a member of HttpContext.Current?  Is there any problem with making that xml file r/o or otherwise not writable by the system acct?

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, your xml file is read, turned into an object or a collection or some .NET data structure. And presumably only xml files of a certain schema can be successfully read this way.

I guess this depends on if there is something interesting in the xml file.  If the xml file is the list of administrators, then as a hypothetical hacker I'd like to modify that file and add my name to the administrators list, which will result in an xml file that still serializes and deserializes to the data structure previous defined in code.

Another way to use write ability, would be to update a price list so that the prices are all free or heavily discounted.

If the XML file is a list of US states, then even if I could modify the list, I'm not sure what I could do with it outside of mischief, which is a larger concern for internet apps than for intranet apps.

I would put the file in the App_Data folder so that it can't be downloaded directly, which will make it harder for a hacker to make correct modifications to it... but security through obscurity is not really a good plan *on it's own*.

Comment: Thank you for answering. I don't think I was able to communicate effectively for you to understand my problem. Another way to look at this problem is to imagine a data layer. At the top of this data layer is the cache layer where the business layer directly get their data. The bottom of this data layer is the file system where the cache gets its data. The argument I hear from co-worker is if you allow the app pool account write data to the file system, then a potential hacker can use that same app pool account to write malicious data into the files that the website consumes. (to be cont.)

Comment: My argument is the hacker doesn't need data to the file system but just the cache since the business layer read directly from the cache and not the file system.

Comment: So what is your goal? To encourage someone to make the files read only? Or to discourage use of the Cache since malicious code could update a value in the cache?  Either way, both attacks require uploading and executing arbitrary code. You could use CAS, maybe to restrict the apps access to the file system, although the Cache (the intrinsic one) is most likely available even in Minimum trust.

Answer (score 0):

If the hacker were to hack the website, then security is compromised anyway. Allowing write access to the XML on it's own shouldn't be an issue, but I wouldn't give this access to any other files within your website.